# Cannot ssh back to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh

I have problems to ssh to my laptop from from a remote machine (let's call it `alice`). 
Both my laptop and `alice` are able to ssh to a third machine (`bob`) and I can ssh back from there to `alice`. However when I try to connect to my laptop from either computers it fails. All three machines are on the same network.

To summarize:

```
@alice       <-> @bob   : Good!
@my_computer  -> @bob   : Good!
@my_computer  -> @alice : Good!
@my_computer <-  @bob   : Fail
@my_computer <-  @alice : Fail
```

I had a look around at other similar questions and I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem.

If I run `sudo systemctl status sshd` I can see that it's active and running.

From `sudo ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The IP that I use to try to connect to my computer is the one that I find running `ifconfig` which is the same that is shown in `$SSH_CONNECTIONS` from `alice` and `bob`.

The messages that I get when trying to connect are

```
me@alice:~$ ssh -vvv andrea@xx.xxx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 7: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 14: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug2: resolving "xx.xxx.xx.xx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xx [xx.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

and

```
me@bob:~$ ssh -vvv andrea@xx.xxx.xx.xx    
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/andrea/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22.
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a firewall between your machine and alice and bob that's dropping your inbound SSH traffic to your machine and but not for outbound. Are all machines on the same network?

Comment: Yes, all three machines are on the same network. I also change my question to make it explicit, since I forgot to mention it. Any suggestion on how I could check that? In the evening I should be able to try the same test with a raspberry pi on my home network.

Comment: open up wireshark on the two test machines, and check on BOTH systems for traffic on port 22. If it's appearing on the sender but not the recipient, you have a network device dropping your inbound SSH packets

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have physical access to `alice` and `bob`, nor can I install wireshark on them :(

Comment: if you can at least get wireshark onto the recipient, then send the SSH requests, you should be okay